# Ping sensor with three or four pins?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I bought a [Ping Ultrasonic Range Finder](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Ping). It has four pins that you connect to the Arduino. I see in Internet that they have three pins. What does represent each pin and where to connect it to? I have an Arduino Uno Starter Kit.

Comment: The sticks (they are really called *pins*) have these little white marks next to them. They're called letters. You read them and they tell you what the pins do.

Comment: @Majenko It's so thin I don't think I will read something there.

Comment: I said *next to* not *on*.

Comment: @Majenko Right, you're right. What does it mean "echo", "vcc" and "Trig"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 *pins*.

- Vcc: +5V supply voltage (it stands for Collector Voltage)
- GND: Ground.
- Trig: Causes an ultrasound pulse to be generated (it stands for *Trigger*)
- Echo: Tells you when an echo has been received.

You can see how to wire and use it here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Easy-ultrasonic-4-pin-sensor-monitoring-hc-sr04/

Comment: In what do I use the trigger pin?

Comment: @PichiWuana That link tells you.